# R: Error while calculating Rolling Median and Rolling Mean

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate 3 period rolling means and rolling medians for the following data:

```
SiteID    Month   TotalSessions TotalMinutes
  1       201401    132            1334
  1       201402    159            2498
  1       201403     98             734
  1       201404    112             909     
  2       201402     25             220
  2       201404     32             407
  4       201401     10              77
  4       201402     12             112
  4       201403      9              59
```

However I am getting an when I use the following function:

```
ave(mydf$TotalSessions, mydf$SiteID, FUN = function(x) rollmedian(x,k=3, align = "right", na.pad = T))
```

Error: k <= n is not TRUE

I understand that the error is because that for some SiteIDs there are less than 3 periods of data and hence the rolling median is not getting calculated.

My question is, is there a way where I can add the missing months with 0s in TotalSessions and Total Minutes so that the data would look as follows:

```
 SiteID    Month   TotalSessions TotalMinutes
  1       201401    132            1334
  1       201402    159            2498
  1       201403     98             734
  1       201404    112             909
  2       201401      0               0
  2       201402     25             220     
  2       201403      0               0
  2       201404     32             407
  4       201401     10              77
  4       201402     12             112
  4       201403      9              59
  4       201404      0               0
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wouldn't that throw your medians off if you are adding 0s? Why did you add a row to site 4? it already had three periods

Comment: Define your own median function `Median <- function(x) if (length(x) < 3) mean(x) else median(x)` and use that with `rollapplyr`.

Comment: @rawr: That should be fine. Because, in my data, if a period of data is not present, then it means that in that particular month, there were no sessions and hence the totalsessions is 0. I added a row to site 4 for reference. In the complete set of data, I have 29 periods with over 150k sites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would use one of the solution proposed in the answer or in comments.

Here an answer to modify your data by adding 0 for missing months(the desired output). I mainly use `merge` function.

```
xx <-  data.frame(Month=unique(dat$Month))
res <- do.call(rbind,
         by(dat,dat$SiteID,function(x)merge(x,xx,all.y=TRUE)))
res[is.na(res)] <- 0

#      Month SiteID TotalSessions TotalMinutes
# 1.1 201401      1           132         1334
# 1.2 201402      1           159         2498
# 1.3 201403      1            98          734
# 1.4 201404      1           112          909
# 2.1 201401      0             0            0
# 2.2 201402      2            25          220
# 2.3 201403      0             0            0
# 2.4 201404      2            32          407
# 4.1 201401      4            10           77
# 4.2 201402      4            12          112
# 4.3 201403      4             9           59
# 4.4 201404      0             0            0
```

Comment: Technically the correct answer, given the OP's comments.

Comment: @agstudy: Thanks for the pointer...Although the solution you mentioned didnt work for my use case, I used the merge function and modified to support my data

Answer (score 3):

Padding with NAs would be better, but even better than that is `rollapply` with `partial = TRUE`:

```
ave(mydf$TotalSessions, mydf$SiteID
    , FUN = function(x) {rollapply(x, 3, median, align = "right", partial = TRUE)})
```

Comment: That seem to work, but why did you change the original column names?

Comment: @nacnudus: That works! Thanks. Any pointers on how to pad with NAs?

Comment: @DavidArenburg to match the code in the original question.  I suppose I ought to have edited the question instead.

Comment: @EsBee, agstudy's padding solution works and is technically the correct answer to your question, given your comment.  My answer will give a different result.